# C - Copying into a struct returns only the last element of each line of file

Tags: c

I am trying to slice each line into substrings, delimited with slashes and load them into a list of structs, but what it does is input only the last element in each line of file.

My file:

```
Adam Mickiewicz///Pan Tadeusz/Publisher 1/1833/24.99
Jules Verne///Around The World in 80 days/Publisher 1/1904/19.99
Jean-Jacques Sempe/Rene Goscinny//Little Nicholas/Publisher 2/1963/22.99
```

My reading algorithm:

```c
struct element
{
    char *authors[AK];
    char *title;
    char *publisher;
    int year;
    float price;

    struct element *next;
};

typedef struct element Book;
char line[1024]; // Buffer
char *string; // Temporary string
char *found = "/";
Book *first = NULL; 
Book *current = NULL;

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    Book *new = malloc(sizeof(Book));
    string = strdup(line); // Duplicate each line in file
    // If encountered a separator, slice the line
    while ((found = strsep(&string, "/")) != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < AK; i++) {
            new->authors[i] = strdup(found);
        }
        new->title = strdup(found);
        new->publisher = strdup(found);
        new->year = atoi(strdup(found));
        new->price = atof(strdup(found));
    }
    if (first == NULL) {
        current = first = new;
    }
    else {
        current = current->next = new;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Authors: 24.99
24.99
24.99
Title: 24.99
Publisher: 24.99
Year: 24
Price: 24.990000
=====================
Authors: 19.99
19.99
19.99
Title: 19.99
Publisher: 19.99
Year: 19
Price: 19.990000
=====================
Authors: 22.99
22.99
22.99
Title: 22.99
Publisher: 22.99
Year: 22
Price: 22.990000
=====================
```

Sorry, if something similar was posted before. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'new->year = atoi(strdup(found));' leak.

Comment: `new->title = strdup(found);
        new->publisher = strdup(found);
        new->year = atoi(strdup(found));
        new->price = atof(strdup(found));` so all those fields have the same value `found` ??

Comment: Note well that data is more important than code.  What is 'book' type?

Comment: You do a while loop on strsep, which winds up having found point to the first character of the final field.  Then you duplicate that field into each member of your struct.   Not clear what you expect to happen that's different.

Comment: Where is your **"list of structs"**?? And note `new` isn't the best choice of names. While legal in C, it is the equivalent of `malloc` in C++.

Comment: Also, what is 'AK'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your loop:

```
while ((found = strsep(&string, "/")) != NULL) {
    for (i = 0; i < AK; i++) {
        new->authors[i] = strdup(found);
    }
    new->title = strdup(found);
    new->publisher = strdup(found);
    new->year = atoi(strdup(found));
    new->price = atof(strdup(found));
}
```

is tokenzing the line until the last field (24.99 for instance) and sets/overwrites all the fields with this very value (with a lot of memory leaks in the process).

You cannot use a loop for that, but extract each token one after the other with x calls to `strsep`

here's my (lame, untested) attempt to fix that:

```
#define NEXT_TOKEN if ((found = strsep(&string, "/")) == NULL) return

     for (i = 0; i < AK; i++) {
       NEXT_TOKEN;
        new->authors[i] = strdup(found);
    }
    NEXT_TOKEN;
    new->title = strdup(found);
    NEXT_TOKEN;
    new->publisher = strdup(found);
    NEXT_TOKEN;
    new->year = atoi(found);
    NEXT_TOKEN;
    new->price = atof(found);
```

the `NEXT_TOKEN` macro avoids copying pasting the cumbersome `strsep` code.

Also, avoid `new` as it's a C++ keyword, making your code C compatible only.

Comment: Looks daunting and repetitive but it worked! Thanks so much man!