# C - How to store arrays from file to a struct

Tags: c

*(Some code might by in portuguese, I tried to translate everything)*

I have a text file like this:

```
    609140307   Carla Aguiar Cunha Paredes Pires    PT 309 181 020 533 713 02F  13.8
    814991297   Ricardo Andrade Nogueira Matos  PT 099 597 635 807 514 05D  10.35
    843818099   Eduardo Carneiro Paredes Clementino Castro  PT 829 961 009 571 587 02D  5.75
    647507641   Cristiana Eanes Almada Martins Baptista PT 257 687 479 093 378 02E  10.35
    684741046   Marisa Calado Cardoso Quadros Barbosa   PT 722 479 016 817 208 0RC  10.35
    945973986   Leonor Leal Estrela Moreira PT 385 455 554 278 760 01D  6.9
    499505062   Paula Nogueira Seixas Carrico   PT 780 968 629 467 061 04E  10.35
    714448831   Carina Carvalheira Ramalho Dinis Valbom PT 025 270 973 606 341 02D  5.75
    ...
    //[contract_id], [name], [street_id], [power]
```

I defined a structure like this:

```
#define MAX 150    
typedef struct contracts {
        int contract_id;
        char name[MAX];
        char street_id[MAX];
        float power;
    } Contracts;
```

My teacher made this function to separate the lines into arrays, returning the variable Res. Res[0] corresponds to contract_id, Res[1] correspondes to name,...

```
#define MAX_LINHA_FICHEIRO 150
#define STRING char *
typedef char LinhaTexto[MAX_LINHA_FICHEIRO];
LinhaTexto LT;
STRING *Read_Split_Line_File(FILE *f, int n_max_fields, int *n_read_fields, char *separators)
    {
        *n_read_fields = 0;
        if (!f) return NULL;
        if (fgets(LT, MAX_LINHA_FICHEIRO, f) != NULL)
        {
        STRING *Res = (STRING *)malloc(n_max_fields * sizeof(STRING)); 
            char *pch = strtok(LT, separators);
            int count = 0;
            while (pch != NULL)
            {
                Res[count] = (char *)malloc((strlen(pch) + 1) * sizeof(char)); 
                strcpy(Res[count++], pch);
                pch = strtok(NULL, separators);
            }
            *n_read_fields = count;

            return Res;
        }
        return NULL;
    };
```

I don't know how and **I need to store all those lines into the struct Contracts**. If you could help me do that I would appreciate it.

Comment: that could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104186/c-copying-into-a-struct-returns-only-the-last-element-of-each-line-of-file

Comment: how do you think the names will be tokenized? there are 4 words each time which one do you want to copy as "name"?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The function splits using separators the separators \t and \n (called in another function). That way the variable name is the full name in the text file.

Comment: Note that the semicolon after the final `}` marks an empty global variable declaration.  It is not part of the function and is absolutely not needed (though it doesn't do much harm unless you have your compiler turned up to very fussy — but you should be compiling with your compiler set to very fussy to make sure you aren't making silly mistakes).

Comment: When the example input contains *tab* characters, you can replace them with `␉` or `⭾` or `⍈`, and note in the text that it corresponds to the horizontal tab character (`'\t'`).

Answer (score 0):

The teacher's code is moderately appalling.  It returns an array of pointers that are dynamically allocated, but they actually point to the global variable `LT`, which is an array of 150 characters.  Consequently, each call to `read_split_line_file()` overwrites the previous data.  Doing the dynamic allocation seems a tad silly.  It would be reasonable to have the calling code provide the array of pointers, and even the line buffer.

However, it appears that you're meant to use the function along the lines of:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(data_file_name, "r");
…error check fp…

enum { MAX_CONTRACT = 150 };
Contracts contract[MAX_CONTRACT];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONTRACT; i++)
{
    char **row;
    int num_fields;
    if ((row = read_split_line_file(fp, 4, &num_fields, "\t")) == 0)
        break;
    if (num_fields != 4)
       …report format error…
    …convert row[0] into contract[i].contract_id;
    …copy    row[1] into contract[i].name;
    …copy    row[2] into contract[i].street_id;
    …convert row[3] into contract[i].power;
    free(row);
}
fclose(fp);
/* You have i valid contracts here */
```

You need to fill in the lines starting with `…` with appropriate code.